# Array declaration & assignment (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-assignment, variable-declaration

A variable declaration and assignment is possible to do within a line, but it seems not possible to do with an array, why?

```
var variable1 = 5;  // Works

var array1[0] = 5;  // Doesn't work

var array2 = [];    // Works
array2[0] = 5;
```

Comment: It doesn't work because when you declare `array1[0]`, it is trying to set the zeroth element of `array1`, which does not exist

Comment: Did you declare array1 as an array? `var array1 = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [*array initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) has the form:

```
var a = [5];
```

When you do:

```
var array1[0]
```

then the interpretter sees `var` and expects it to be followed by an identifier. However, `array1[0]` is not a valid identifier due to the "[" and "]" characters. If they were, you'd have a variable named *array1[0]* that has the value `5`.

Answer (score 1):

`var array1 = [5];` initializes array1 to an array literal with a single element 5.

Note that array1 is not a constant array, elements can be pushed, read, changed, etc.

The above line has the same effect as

```
var array1 = [];
array1[0] = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it:

```
var array2 = [5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use var when pushing to an array because it interprets as "array1[0]" - using characters that aren't allowed, but also you need to set the array first

```
var array1 = [];
array1[0] = 5;  // Yes it does

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's just the wrong way, i guess.

```
var array1 = [5];
var array2 = [3,4,5];
```

is the way you wanna do it.